# Idris impossible keyword proves a wrong proposition

Tags: functional-programming, idris, dependent-type, theorem-proving

```
data Even: Nat -> Type where
  EvenZ: Even Z
  EvenS: Even n -> Even (n + 2)

total
lemma1: Even Z
lemma1 = EvenZ

-- total
-- lemma2: Even Z
-- lemma2 impossible -- Idris says 'lemma2 is a valid case' and I agree with you

total
lemma3: Even 2
lemma3 = EvenS EvenZ

total
lemma4: Even 2 -> Void
lemma4 x impossible -- what does it work?

total
lemma5: Even 1 -> Void
lemma5 x impossible
```

I wrote some proofs on `Even`.

`lemma1`, `lemma2` and `lemma3` are ok, but `lemma4` looks strange to me.
AFAIK, both `lemma3` and `lemma4` can not be provable at the same time.
I expected `impossible` keyword in lemma4 not to work and expected Idris to show me some error messages about the wrong usage of `impossible`.

Is `impossible` an unsafe keyword that can be used to assert to type checker?

Comment: `impossible` should be safe, thus this is simply a bug you might want to report (though most work now is spent on Idris 2.0). A usual workaround to `impossible` problems is to case split `x` first and then try to make the cases impossible (which would report that `lemma4 (EvenS _) is a valid case`).

Comment: Interestingly, when you give `lemma5` the same treatment, you **also** get that error message. :/